# Sharepoint Desinger Workflow --> Grant Permission on Item

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I am designing the custom workflow using Sharepoint Designer. I would like to grant the permission on each task once it created by workflow.  In order to do that I am trying to select

Workflow Desinger --> Actions --> Grant Permission on Item.

But somehow, I can cannot select this action. Any idea?

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Workflows run within the context of the user that starts the workflow. They might not have permissions to grant new permissions. Try adding an Impersonation Step and adding the Grant Permission action inside that. Impersonation runs as the user that saves the workflow.

Comment: I am using Sharepoint 2007 --> SPD. I don't see Impersonation in the Action.

Answer (score 0):

"Grant Permission on Item" is not a standard out-of-the-box SPD workflow action for SharePoint 2007 (WSS or MOSS).

djeeg's reply was assuming that you were working in Visual Studio on a custom workflow action, not in SharePoint designer.

Ultimately, you'll either need to build your own custom action for this, or use one like http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/ . In either case, you're not being nearly specific enough here.